# Using an external .dat file with a python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a python script to read statistics off of a file: savegame.dat

http://pastebin.com/DmsHfPhU is the script

The script came with instructions: "Use: python %script% %savegame.dat%"

I have python, I don't know where to put the savegame.dat file.

For some reason python launcher isn't working so I have to do it manually through the Terminal using the "python" command. I tried putting it in the same folder and it didn't work. I'd like to know what I need to change in the raw paste so it recognizes the savegame.dat. I tried dragging the script into the Terminal.app after opening the python command. With the script saved in the same place as .dat file.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the same directory as you are running the script in.

Save the paste in the link to a file.  Call it foo.py.  Put foo.py and the .dat file in the same directory.

Open the terminal.app.  `cd` to the directory that both files are in, then type `python foo.py savegame.dat`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you put the file so long as you specify the full path to it on the command line.